# Transferring data from server to server MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a situation that my company post events in calendar on our website server and they show in website, but in lobby we have a screen that shows today events, but from another database which has to be updated manually.
My job is to make it automatic.

I have to copy data from one database to another. 
Each database has 2 folders.
first database(one im copying from) contains 2 tables
And second database another 2 tables
[Link to both databases][1]
Im dont have enough reputation to post pictures.

What i must do : insert into table **_nodarbibas** fields *time_start*,*time_end* values from table **web_notikumi_laiki** fields *not_laiks*,*not_laiks_lidz*.
And into table **_nodarbibas_ln** field *text* I have to insert *not_nosaukums* from table **web_notikumi**
Also I must get only  those entries where **web_notikumi**.not_vieta='ZRKAC'.

My idea of doing this (and what have I done so far)

All table basically have same information so I decided that I could give events in tables **_nodarbibas** and **_nodarbibas_ln** ID's from **web_notikumi** table

So I inserted into table **_nodarbibas_ln**(id,text) values from **web_notikumi** table (id_not,not_nosaukums) where *not_vieta* ='ZRKAC'.

*Now I have all events here that I will need*

then I inserted into table **_nodarbibas** (id) value from **_nodarbibas_ln**(id)
now I want to insert  into table**_nodarbibas**(*time_start*,*time_end*) values from **web_notikumi_laiki**(not_laiks,not_laiks_lidzi) where **web_notikumi_laiki**.not_id=**_nodarbibas**.id.
So I write

```
INSERT into c3_zrkac._nodarbibas(id,time_start,time_end) 
SELECT not_id,not_laiks,not_laiks_lidz 
FROM www_jirpic_lv.web_notikumi_laiki 
WHERE c3_zrkac._nodarbibas.id=www_jirpic_lv.web_notikumi_laiki.not_id
```

> but sql says :
>
> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'c3_zrkac._nodarbibas.id' in 'where clause'

I read online that it could be something about where clause executing first but I cant find a way around this.

I will highly appreciate any help with this or ideas how to do it different.

Comment: you define the objects 'available' in the `WHERE` clause in the `FROM` part of the query. you filter on a field of the table `c3_zrkac._nodarbibas` that is not in in the `FROM` clause hence the error. anyway the query looks odd because it looks like you want to insert data that you expect to be in the target...